# Type error in connected container component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

I'm converting a React app to TypeScript, and my app container component contains these container components:

#### `App.tsx`

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <AppContainer>
        <HeaderContainer />
        <TabContainer />
        <ViewContainer />
      </AppContainer>
    )
  }
}

export default App
```

#### `HeaderContainer.tsx`

```
const mapStateToProps = (state: AppState) => ({version: state.settings.version})

const mapDispatchToProps = () => ({})

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(Header)
```

#### `Header.tsx`

```
const HeaderContainer = styled('header')({
    flex: '0 0 auto',
    flexDirection: 'row-reverse',
});
const HeaderRow = styled('div')({
    padding: '10px 0px 0px 0px',
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'row-reverse',
    justifyContent: 'right',
    maxHeight: '100px',
});

const HeaderLogo = styled('img')({
    margin: '0px 5px',
    height: '80px',
    width: '80px',
    display: 'flex',
    order: 1,
});

const HeaderInfo = styled('div')({
    margin: '0px 15px 0px 10px',
    display: 'flex',
    justifyContent: 'flex-start',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    order: 0,
});

const HeaderName = styled('div')({
    display: 'flex',
    marginTop: '7px',
    flexGrow: 1,
    order: 0,
    fontSize: '40px',
});

const HeaderVersion = styled('div')({
    display: 'flex',
    flexGrow: 1,
    order: 1,
    fontSize: '20px',
});
const Header = ({ version }) => (
  <HeaderContainer>
    <Disclaimer />
    <HeaderRow>
        <HeaderLogo src={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + "/icons/icon-512x512.png"} alt="logo" />
        <HeaderInfo>
            <HeaderName>App Name</HeaderName>
            <HeaderVersion>{version}</HeaderVersion>
        </HeaderInfo>
    </HeaderRow>
  </HeaderContainer>
)

Header.propTypes = {
  version: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
}

export default Header
```

I'm getting a type error on `HeaderContainer` in `App.tsx`:

`Type error: Property 'version' is missing in type '{}' but required in type 'Pick<InferProps<{ version: Validator<string>; }>, "version">'.`

I do basically understand what this is saying. However, I don't get why the error is showing up on `HeaderContainer` and not in `Header`, and I don't get why the error is showing up at all because `Header` is only being implemented inside of the `connect` function in the container, passing it the required prop.

Commenting out the `propTypes` in `Header` silences the error.

Answer (score 0):

are you using the version prop anywhere inside your styled component?
you might have to pass `version` directly to the styled component like so `const Header = styled.div<HeaderProps>`

where `HeaderProps` is:

```
interface HeaderProps {
    version: type
}
```

Comment: I've posted the full code. `version` doesn't occur anywhere in the styled code, but it's used inside `<HeaderVersion>` in the final component itself, if that's what you mean. I tried `const HeaderVersion = styled('div')<{version: string}>({` but that didn't fix anything.